# Word limiter in Codeigniter, how to echo words after the limit?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter word_limiter() function in the text helper.

```
$string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";

$string = word_limiter($string, 4);

// Returns: Here is a nice…
```

The above functions limit the output to four words. How can I also store the words after the limit in a variable for use too???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$original_string = "Here is a nice text string consisting of eleven words.";
$limited_string = word_limiter($original_string , 4, '');
$rest_of_string = trim(str_replace($limited_string, "", $original_string));
```